# This site can’t be reached took too long to respond in cakephp 3 application

Tags: cakephp

When page loads in my cakephp 3 application it shows that This site can’t be reached took too long to respond in cakephp 3 application in all browser.
why this application show error any body can help me.

is there are a way to know why is the problem can be occurred.? is it my coding problem or other issues

Comment: your question is vague, please add more details.for instance you should first try to remove all your processing code and just load very basic html

Comment: Insert some debugging code to find the place where it goes wrong. E.g. you could add a `die();` at the beginning of your controller. If the server sends back a blank page, you know the problem has not occured yet. Then move the `die();` down the code and fnd the place where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

**There are too many reason for this issue:**

- Properly not Routing
- Redirecting to same URL
- CSS/JS etc from CDN and CDN url taking too many loading time
  etc

**Basic Solution:**

- Check you configured your application routing properly.
- Debug your code is not Redirecting to same url too many times
- Ckeck CDN links from browser console, If CDN links take too many times, Use CSS/JS other assets from Local

> **Note :** There is also other issues